# In general, will a lot of small function calls harm performance?

Tags: c++

Let's say I need to do three tasks. The first option is like this:

```
void doAllStuffInOneFunc() {
     //code block for task 1
     ...
     ...
     //code block for task 2
     ...
     ...
     //code block for task 3
     ...
     ...
 }
```

Or, the following may be better for readability and maintenance:

```
 void doAllStuffByCallingOtherFuncs() {
      doTask1();
      doTask2();
      doTask3();
}
```

What will I pay for the second option?

Comment: You will pay only a little overhead for calling functions like that. You should use the more easy maintainable solution.

Comment: It depends on how your compiler optimises - better to try both ways and profile the release builds. Go for code clarity and modularity first.

Comment: Please code for readability! Each function should do 1 task!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the code is "known" in the compile unit, and the function is not overly complex, most modern compilers will inline the code anyway. If the function is also declared `static`, then it will not generate a "real function".

Edit 3:

Explanation on `static`: When a free function (not a member of a class) is available to make inline, if the compiler isn't sure that all places this function is called are inlined, it produces an out-of-line function (aka "real function") as well.

If a free function is declared `static` it tells the compiler that this function is "local to this compile unit", so nothing else will ever call this function. If the compiler then inlines all calls in this compile unit, then it doesn't need to produce an "out-of-line" function as well, since the compiler can know all the calls to the function.

Note also that taking the address of a function will also force the compiler to make an out-of-line function, since the function pointer must point somewhere [although under very special circumstances, I've seen compilers inline functions called through function pointers too]

As with all performance matters, if it's really critical in your application, then benchmarking the actual code (and different variants of it), and profiling, is key to getting things right. There is no such thing as "this is the right answer", different compilers (on different platforms) with different settings will do different things.

Edit: Unless there is evidence that the code is worthwhile the penalty of being less readable, don't sacrifice readability for optimisation. Very little of the overall code is typically important for performance anyway.

Edit2: If you can also REUSE some of the code in other functions, that's an extra bonus. But making code readable is the key goal of splitting into functions in the first place, typically.

Comment: Would you mind to explain a little bit on `static --> not a "read function"?`

Answer (score 6):

It depends:

- On the overall overhead for function calls on the target architecture.
- On the overhead of passing any arguments.
- On the overhead of handling any return values.
- On whether or not the compiler decides to inline the calls.

The version with the separate steps broken out into their own functions (which, crucially, provides them with *a name*) is much much better and should be preferred in all cases, and only removed if serious profiling and testing proves that the manually inlined version is really better.

This of course can only happen if the code in question is on a performance-critical path to begin with.

Comment: Not to mention the number of times, `doAllStuffByCallingOtherFuncs` is called

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the function. If they are inlined you pay nothing. If they are not you pay one jump. The costs of it you can not easily predict. it depends on the address you are jumping to as it may occur as TLB miss.

Obviously you have to take into account things like optimization levels etc. 
General rule is that if you dont call it in the loop you should aim rather for code readablity than such small optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

The second option results in clearer code. It will easier to maintain your code and better for you to test them separately. Though there will be some cost for function calls,  modern compilers may optimize the cost away.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example I assume you are coding each task inline. This will be faster in general.

As I understand it: 
The penalty you pay in the second example is a small one. You'll be allocating any memory you need for the parameters onto the stack (assuming you'll be passing by value here). You might find [this link a nice read](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.8.html).
Depending on the number of function calls within each of those sub tasks, the depth of your stack will get larger and larger. If you plan on calling hugely recursive functions within any of those you'll be getting down to a recursive limit and your program might run out of memory if you're not careful. 
If you wanted to, you could generate the assembly for the code you have and look at how it's actually calling the functions. A JMP in the assembly or some other type of GoTo operation will probably need to resolve whatever label its going to and that might add a small amount of time depending on the size of your program. Really though, you're not incurring much overhead by using the functions. And if you declared them inline, they'd be written inline by the compiler for code execution and would run just as fast as if you'd written them that way in the first place. [You can check out more on inline functions here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-functions.html)

My personal opinion is that the second way is the way to go if each of those sub tasks are fairly independent from each other and/or large blocks of code. It will be easier to maintain and track down any errors if you run into them. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the hardware and how often you'll be making calls. But in general, unless your target audience has something absurdly ancient, it should not harm performance significantly.

In general, it's far better to have code readable and maintainable than to worry about performance.

Answer (score 0):

In general no.

Calls are very fast and do not influence the overall performance that much. If your tasks are very havy you cannot measure the performance loss. If the task is very small the compiler will probably inline it, which means the call is removed by optimization automatically.

Calls become more expensive if:

1. There are lots of parameters
2. The parameters are non-elementary types as std::string and get copied. You can avoid this by using references (const std::string&)
3. The call is virtual (only possible in classes where you used polymorphy)

To check the performance for a special case (your program) you can use a porfiler. Such programs will tell you were the most performance is lost. Start to optimize there.